# Second-Order RLC Circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

How do I find the second-order differential equation, in terms of \$i(t)\$?

At time \$t>0\$, the voltage source will be gone, and I will have a parallel \$RLC\$. I am having problems with finding the equation because I used nodal analysis, and now I have an equation in terms of \$v(t)\$ instead of \$i(t)\$. What would be the equation?
How do I get this equation?

Further, I just want to confirm. At \$t\$ is in \$\infty\$, and there is a circuit, the circuit will be in steady state, and the capacitor will be in open circuit, and the inductor will be short circuit. Is it?

[image]

Comment: At t=infinity the cap is OPEN, the inductor is short and the current is zero. (Assuming like you said the switch OPENS at t=0.)

Comment: What would be the second order eequation at t>0?

Comment: Is the circuit in steady-state when the switch is opened at t=0? If so, and you have the equation you wrote for v(t) which is presumably the junction of the 2 ohm resistors, write v(t) in terms of i(t) and you've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the voltage source at \$t=0\$ is just supplying some charge to the capacitor, and the differential equation would just be the decaying transient response of the RLRC circuit with an initial capacitor voltage of 8V (v_c(0) = 8V).

So yes, at \$t -> ∞\$, \$i(t) = 0\$; there would be no voltage drop across any component, there would be no current flowing through any component.

By the definition of a capacitor:
$$ i_c(t) = C\frac{\mathrm{d}V_c(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}, $$
Since the voltage across C is the same as the voltage across R and RL:
$$ Vc(t) = R{i(t)} + L\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = Ri_r(t), $$
And since \$i_r(t) + i(t) = i_c(t) = \frac{v_c(t)}{R} + i(t)\$.

It has been a while since I have solved differential equations, but I think this simplifies to:
$$ i_c(t) = C\left[R\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} + L\frac{\mathrm{d^2}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\right]= {i(t)} + \frac{L}{R}\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} + i(t) $$

$$ i_c(t) = 2\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d^2}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = {i(t)} + \frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} + i(t) $$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d^2}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + 0.5\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} - i(t) = 0 $$

Comment: what if there is a voltage source when t approaches infinity? What will happen to the circuit?, and is the second term supposed to be 1.5?

Comment: No, not 1.5.  I divided everything by 2 after subtracting.  But do it yourself and check the math... as I could have made some other mistake ;) .

As for a voltage source as t -> ∞, do you mean that for all t the voltage source is still present (the switch is never opened)?  You could write an ODE in Vc(t), but for a constant DC driven circuit the steady-state solution is pretty easy (cap open for DC).  The transient response, while C charges, can be obtained from the ODE in Vc(t).